# How to automate the backup of all VMs on a Hyper-V instance

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server

I want to schedule a script which will automatically backup all the servers on my Hyper-V instance, which are all Windows Server 2012/2012 R2.

I have code which asks user to give parameters and then it takes backup.

I can see two options:

1. make a .txt file which will contain all the VM names on Hyper V but updating that file, whenever we add a new VM, will be hectic. so I **wouldn't** prefer doing this.
2. we can remove the function where it takes input from user and add "get-vm" command somewhere? I don't know how to do this.

Below is the code I want to use.

```
#requires -version 3.0
#requires -module Hyper-V

<#
.SYNOPSIS
Export virtual machines
.DESCRIPTION
This utility will export virtual machines to a target destination. By default
it will create a folder using the format:

Weekly_Year_Month_Day_HourSecond

The script will delete the oldest folder once 4 subfolders have been created.
Use the -Monthly parameter to do the same thing but for folders that begin
with Monthly, i.e. Monthly_Year_Month_Day_HourSecond.

Because the export process can be time consuming, you can use the -AsJob parameter
which will be passed to Export-VM. You will then get PowerShell background jobs
which you can manage with the standard job cmdlets.

This script must be run as an administrator in an elevated session.

.PARAMETER VM
A comma separated list of virtual machines. You can also pipe Get-VM into
this command. This parameter has an alias of Name.
.PARAMETER Path
The path to the top level backup or export folder.
.PARAMETER Monthly
Run the script in Monthly mode
.PARAMETER AsJob
Export virtual machines using background jobs
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> get-vm chi-dc01,chi-dc02 | c:\scripts\ScheduledExport.ps1 -path e:\export

Get the virtual machines, CHI-DC01 and CHI-DC02 and pipe them to the script which will
export them to the given folder.

.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> c:\scripts\ScheduledExport.ps1 "CHI-DC01","CHI-FP01" -path E:\Export -asjob

Export virtual machines CHI-DC01 and CHI-FP01 to a weekly folder under E:\Export.

.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> get-content c:\work\vms.txt | c:\scripts\ScheduledExport.ps1 -asjob -monthly

Read the text file, vms.txt, and pass each virtual machine name to the script. This will
use the Monthly backup folders. Exports will be done as jobs.

.LINK
Get-VM
Export-VM
#>

[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True,
HelpMessage="Enter the virtual machine name or names",
ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[Alias("name")]
[string[]]$VM,

[Parameter(Position=1)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[string]$Path = "C:\work\export",

[Parameter(Position=2)]
[switch]$Monthly,

[Parameter(Position=3)]
[switch]$AsJob
)

Begin {

#define some variables if we are doing weekly or monthly backups
if ($monthly) {
  $type = "Monthly"
  $retain = 2
}
else {
   $type = "Weekly"
   $retain = 4
}

Write-Verbose "Processing $type backups. Retaining last $retain."

#get backup directory list
Try {
 Write-Verbose "Checking $path for subfolders"
 
 #get only directories under the path that start with Weekly or Monthly
 $subFolders =  dir -Path $path\$type* -Directory -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Failed to enumerate folders from $path"
    #bail out of the script
    return
}

#check if any backup folders
if ($subFolders) {
    #if found, get count
    Write-Verbose "Found $($subfolders.count) folder(s)"
    
    #if more than the value of $retain, delete oldest one
    if ($subFolders.count -ge $retain ) {
       #get oldest folder based on its CreationTime property
       $oldest = $subFolders | sort CreationTime | Select -first 1 
       Write-Verbose "Deleting oldest folder $($oldest.fullname)"
       #delete it
       $oldest | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    }
      
 } #if $subfolders
else {
    #if none found, create first one
    Write-Verbose "No matching folders found. Creating the first folder"    
}

#create the folder
#get the current date
$now = Get-Date

#name format is Type_Year_Month_Day_HourMinute
$childPath = "{0}_{1}_{2:D2}_{3:D2}_{4:D2}{5:D2}" -f $type,$now.year,$now.month,$now.day,$now.hour,$now.minute

#create a variable that represents the new folder path
$new = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $childPath

Try {
    Write-Verbose "Creating $new"
    #Create the new backup folder
    $BackupFolder = New-Item -Path $new -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Stop 
}
Catch {
  Write-Warning "Failed to create folder $new. $($_.exception.message)"
  #failed to create folder so bail out of the script
  Return
}
} #end begin

Process {

#only process if a backup folder was created
if ($BackupFolder) {
    #export VMs
    #define a hashtable of parameters to splat to Export-VM
    $exportParam = @{
     Path = $new
     Name=$Null
     ErrorAction="Stop"
    }
    if ($asjob) {
      Write-Verbose "Exporting as background job"
      $exportParam.Add("AsJob",$True)
    }

    Write-Verbose "Exporting virtual machines"
    <#
     Go through each virtual machine name, and export it using Export-VM
    #>
    foreach ($name in $VM) {
        $exportParam.Name=$name
        #if the user did not include -WhatIf then the machine will be exported
        #otherwise they will get a WhatIf message
        if ($PSCmdlet.shouldProcess($name)) {
           Try {
                Export-VM @exportParam
           }
           Catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to export virtual machine(s). $($_.Exception.Message)"
           }
        } #whatif
    } #close foreach
} #if backup folder exists 
} #Process
End {
    Write-Host "Export script finished." -ForegroundColor Green

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-VM` [cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848479.aspx) can list all of the VMs on a given system. Combine that with example in help text that is included in the pasted script:

```
get-vm chi-dc01,chi-dc02 | c:\scripts\ScheduledExport.ps1 -path e:\export
```

should result in a save all virtual machines statement, like so

```
get-vm  | c:\scripts\ScheduledExport.ps1 -path e:\export
```

Comment: and how do i write network path "\\storage\backup" ? when i try writing it like -path \\storage\backup it doesn't work :/  @vonPryz

Comment: @user4807619 You need to be more specific than that. What, exactly, does "doesn't work" mean? No export, broken export, wrong location, error message..?

Comment: actually it wasn't giving any error message via task scheduler. but it worked fine with powershell prompt. I figured the missing " " after the arguments. I was writing -computername server instead of  -computername  "server". which  successfully took the backup with prompt  but it automatically halted and gave successful completion message with task scheduler without even creating backup file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like these operations are highly prone to human errors. Why cannot use third-party solutions instead of scripts for Hyper-V backup? (Personally, I recommend [Handy Backup](http://www.handybackup.net/hyper-v-backup.shtml), but it is because this solution is one I have on my job, and, perhaps, backup software other companies may also contain Hyper-V backup functions?)